# 2000s (I think) YA Fantasy novel series with pendant or stone on cover

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a very long shot as I don't remember too much about this series, as I read it after I had a heavy brain concussion.

The setting was a medieval-time fantasy setting, I'm pretty sure there was magic involved.
Each book in the series had a different color stone or pendant on the cover which was associated with a different character.

There were multiple main characters that may or may not have special powers and I feel like they were connected through the pendants/stones.

Also not entirely sure if I remember it correctly, but I think one of the main characters had something to do with noticing/sensing or ending a pregnancy of another main character.

I read it in the early 2000s, bought it in a Dutch bookstore, if that's of any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

Is this the ***[Deltora Quest](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41221-deltora-quest)*** series by Emily Rodda...?

- Book 1: *[The Forests of Silence](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/155238.The_Forests_of_Silence)* (2000)
- Book 2: *[The Lake of Tears](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119494.The_Lake_of_Tears)* (2000)
- Book 3: *[City of the Rats](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119493.City_of_the_Rats)* (2000)
- Book 4: *[The Shifting Sands](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119490.The_Shifting_Sands)* (2000)
- Book 5: *[Dread Mountain](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119495.Dread_Mountain)* (2000)
- Book 6: *[The Maze of the Beast](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119489.The_Maze_of_the_Beast)* (2001)
- Book 7: *[The Valley of the Lost](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119492.The_Valley_of_the_Lost)* (2001)
- Book 8: *[Return to Del](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119491.Return_to_Del)* (2001)

It fits the timeframe, and each book in the series has a different-coloured stone on the cover.

Here's the Goodreads synopsis for the first book:

> The evil Shadow Lord is plotting to invade Deltora and enslave its people. All that stands against him is the magic Belt of Deltora with its seven gems of great and mysterious power. When the gems are stolen and hidden in dark terrible places throughout the kingdom, the Shadow Lord triumphs, and Deltora is lost.
>
> In secrecy, with only a hand-drawn map to guide them, two unlikely companions set out on a perilous quest. Determined to find the lost gems and rid their land of the tyrant, they struggle towards their first goal - the sinister Forests of Silence.

[image]